# How could I solve this error please (IndexError: list index out of range)?

Tags: python, list

I have the following work in Python. I'm trying to solve an equation by using Python and showing the results by plotting it. When I run my following below code, I got this error below:

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raineen\Desktop\Raneen_Python\Sigma_theta_c.py", line 44, in <module>
    segma.append((((Tt*Ct[count])/(2*t0*lambda1))*((m.log(item*r))**Nt[count]))+(((Tb*Cb)/(2*t0*lambda1))*((m.log(item*r))**Nb))+((Tt*Ct[count])/(t0*lambda1*(Nt[count]+1)))*((m.log(item*r))**(Nt[count]+1)-(m.log(item*R0))**(Nt[count]+1))+ ((Tb*Cb)/(t0*lambda1*(Nb+1)))*((m.log(item*r))**(Nb+1)-(m.log(item*R0))**(Nb+1)))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have three lists and I'm looping through them at the same time, they are:

```
t = [x/100 for x in range(1, 201)] # [0.01,0.02,0.02,..........,2]

Ct=  [126.0, 127.82549463360013, 129.67743712955985, 131.55621066590138, 133.46220397215035, 135.39581140976628, 137.35743305373825, 139.34747477536274, 141.36634832622116, 143.41447142337327]

a=  [39.960039960039964, 19.960079840319363, ..........]
```

Could I get any help to fix this problem, please?

**The Python**

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lambda1 = 1
t = [x/100 for x in range(1, 201)]
t0 = 2
Tt = 1.5
Kt = 126
Kb = 1261
Rt = 5
Nt = [x/10 for x in range(0, 10)]
Nb = 0.36
Tb = 0.5
r = 6.5


R0 = Rt + t0
z = 2/m.sqrt(3)
#Ct = Kt*(z**Nt)
Cb = Kb*(z**Nb)


print('t= ', t)
print('Nt= ', Nt)
Ct = []
for n in Nt:
    Ct.append(Kt*(z**n))

Rm = []
for j in t:
    Rm.append(5+(j/2))

print('Rm= ',Rm)
print('Ct= ',Ct)

a = []
for k,i in zip(Rm,t):
    a.append(t0/(k*i))
    print(k, i)
print('a= ',a)

segma = []
for count, item in enumerate(a):
    segma.append((((Tt*Ct[count])/(2*t0*lambda1))*((m.log(item*r))**Nt[count]))+(((Tb*Cb)/(2*t0*lambda1))*((m.log(item*r))**Nb))+((Tt*Ct[count])/(t0*lambda1*(Nt[count]+1)))*((m.log(item*r))**(Nt[count]+1)-(m.log(item*R0))**(Nt[count]+1))+ ((Tb*Cb)/(t0*lambda1*(Nb+1)))*((m.log(item*r))**(Nb+1)-(m.log(item*R0))**(Nb+1)))

print('Sigma_theta_c = ', segma)

##for i in segma:
##    print(i)

plt.plot(t,segma)

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('Sigma_theta_c')


plt.show()
```

This is below the equation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and the problem is that the **length** of `Ct` and `Nt` arrays is `10` while the length of list `a` is 200.
In this case you are enumerating a list `a` and using `count` to access the elements in lists `Ct` and `Nt` which causes `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

General way to solve similar problems like this - check out length of the lists you are accessing, creating. Could you share full equations and your domain model? What exactly are you solving? What's the desired input and output?

len(t) # 200

len(segma) # 10

plt.plot(segma) works and actually creates the plot

[image]

Comment: Wikiiel, I have added the equation that I have and I need the plot between **t** and **segma**. I need in every time to take one state of Nt and loop over the two other lists and make a draw, then take the second state from the Nt and loop through the two others and make a draw and so on.....